# How can I update a field in the PFUser.currentUser() object?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I feel very stupid for asking this, but for the life of me, I am unable to figure this out. I just need to take the value of my "wants" field and add 1 to it.

My code is here:

```
var user = PFUser.currentUser()
let number = user["wants"]
user["wants"] = number + 1
user.save()
```

Please help me! I'm sure this is probably a very simple process and I'm probably overthinking it!

Comment: What error is this giving you?

Comment: "Cannot subscript a value of type 'PFUser?' with an index of type 'String'"

Comment: check if my answer works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a counter, you could update it using

```
PFUser.currentUser().incrementKey("Wants")
```

and then save the object

more info at the official parse documentation

[Parse User docs](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Is there a function like incrementKey() that instead of adding one, subtracts one?

Comment: Try incrementKey by amount and specify a negative value. https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-saving-objects

Comment: Thanks for marking as answer. An upvote would also be appreciated

Comment: I would love to upvote, but I'm new to the site and I don't have enough reputation yet. XD